# How can I display data from the same table side by side

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, inner-join

Say I have 1 table in mysql (called get) like this:

```
ID S Num
00 1 506
00 2 620
01 1 562
01 2 564
02 1 548
02 2 484
03 1 488
03 2 895
```

I am trying to get it in this format:

```
ID S1  S2
00 506 620
01 562 564
02 548 484
03 488 895
```

So far I have this, but it gives me an error:

```
select id,d.S1,c.S2 from 
(select S as S1 from get where S=1)d inner join  
(select s as S2 from get where S=2)c using (id);
```

I am still not too sure about joins, but this seems to make sense.

EDIT: S can have only 1 value at times, in these times, this value will be S1

Comment: You said you have two tables but you also showed one table data.

Comment: Yes, i just edited it, its only one table, basically referencing 1 table twice, but for different information

Comment: Will your `Id` values always have a value for `S=1` and `S=2`?  Are there cases when you will have only one value for S?

Comment: Good point, yes there maybe times when there is only 1 value for s, thanks, didn't account for that

Comment: @user2883071 If that is the case, then would `s=1` always be a value?

Comment: yes, S1 would always be there

Comment: This requires a pivot query, which mysql doesn't support. The workarounds to simulate make for VERY ugly queries and VERY quickly become unmaintainable. Do the transform in your client code and use a standard query to get the data.

Comment: @MarcB `PIVOT` is syntax sugar for `SUM(CASE WHEN ... THEN 1|number ELSE 0 END)`

Comment: @swasheck: yes, but full pivot support allows abitrary numbers of fields to be specified, WITHOUT having to hack in a per-column sum().

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a self-join, in other words you can join on your table twice similar to the way you started.  Since you stated that `S=1` will always exist, then you can use the following query:

```
select t1.id,
  t1.num S1,
  t2.num S2
from yourtable t1
left join yourtable t2
  on t1.id = t2.id
  and t2.s = 2
where t1.s = 1;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/54000/3).  Using a LEFT JOIN on your table will return all rows with the value of `S=1` even if `S=2` doesn't exist in your table.

You could also use an aggregate function with a CASE expression to get the result:

```
select
  id,
  sum(case when s = 1 then num end) S1,
  sum(case when s = 2 then num end) S2
from yourtable
group by id;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/54000/4)

Comment: Yes, the left join does not work, however the cases option works fine.
thank you.

Comment: However, if I want to manipulate the data, how would I implement it?
example:
avg(case when s = 1 then (num*8) end) S1
gives an error

Comment: @user2883071 Create a new question; it's out of scope of your original question.

Comment: Got it, 
(sum(case when s = 2 then num end)*8) S2

Answer (score 0):

Though a JOIN may not be the best way to go about it, you can achieve the desired result by

```
SELECT t1.id, t.Num [S1], t2.Num [S2]
FROM Table t1
LEFT JOIN Table t2 ON t1.id = t2.id AND t1.s <> t2.s
```

Also refer to [PIVOT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table) in case there may be other values in the S column of your table.

EDIT: Changed the `INNER JOIN` to a `LEFT JOIN` after seeing the comment that said that there may be id's with no S = 2.